# Email a link option in SharePoint 2013 is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server

In the SharePoint list, Under **LIST** tab Email a link button is working fine.
But under **ITEMS** tab, if we select an item, the Email a link button is getting enabled, but on clicking it it is not working.
If we are editing the item and in it's edit page also the Email a link button is getting enabled, but on clicking it it is not working.

Can anyone please tell me with the reason for this and update me the solution ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any custom action/control? As there is no OOTB Email a link button in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Place of this.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl(), replaced it with _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl . After this email a link is working

Comment: Since your issue is solve, you can mark your reply as an answer. It will benefits many other users who met the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you referring to the Email a link button under ITEMS tab?

Has anyone added the Email a link button manually?

I can only find Email a link button under LIST tab, while i cannot find Email a link button under ITEMS tab.

[image]

Comment: Yes, The Email a link button is added through custom code, but this button is working fine in SharePoint 2010. When it is migrated to SharePoint 2013 it is not working

Comment: Since it not work after migration. I am afraid that you may need to re-create a new button for desired function.

Comment: Thankyou. By doing small modifications in the code, the issue is resolved.

Comment: In Place of this.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl(), replaced it with _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl . After this email a link is working